# DIR function in vba works diffrent when passing a value directly and by a variable

Tags: excel, vba, directory

Hi i have some files *in a particular folder in my system when i use *the below** code it gives all the files in that folder (passing the path directly)

```
filenm = Dir("C:\Documents and Settings\murugan.k\Desktop\Daily report automation\Eve report\trial\")

Do Until filenm = ""
ActiveSheet.Cells(ctr, 12).Value = filenm
ctr = ctr + 1
filenm = Dir()
Loop
```

but when i store the same path in a variable and pass the varible to the dir function it gives me only two files (AUTOEXEC.BAT & bar.emf)

```
filenm = Dir(pth)
Do Until filenm = ""
ActiveSheet.Cells(ctr, 12).Value = filenm
ctr = ctr + 1
filenm = Dir()
Loop
```

could some one please help me in resolving this problem because i can't hard code the path in macro  which has to be dynamic (changes as per user)

Answer (score 1):

Try different attributes for the [Dir() function](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/dir.php).

```
path = "C:\Documents and Settings\murugan.k\Desktop\" & _ 
        "Daily report automation\Eve report\trial\"

filenm = Dir(path, vbNormal)

Do Until filenm = ""
    ActiveSheet.Cells(ctr, 12).Value = filenm
    ctr = ctr + 1
    filenm = Dir()
Loop
```

Comment: this also gives me same output AUTOEXEC.BAT & bar.emf

Comment: @murugan_kotheesan can you physically check the contents of the folder specified in the path? What files does it have? Have you tried to navigate to the folder using `cmd` and displaying the files?

Comment: Both your version and @mehow's work as expected. Both pull a list of files from the directory, both from a direct string or from an `strPath`variable. Are you sure there's more than the two files in that Directory?

Comment: @mehow yes i have checked the folder and it contins 5 csv files and 2 .xlx files

Answer (score 0):

i some how got his correct

b4 i have the path without"\" at the end so i concatenate the path with "\" and put that in anothe variable and i pass that variable to DIR function (which din't work) but now i have added "\" at the end of folder path in the input itself and i pass that varible to DIR it works now

```
'            checking the available files
filenm = Dir(File_pth)
Do Until filenm = ""
ActiveSheet.Cells(ctr, 12).Value = filenm
ctr = ctr + 1
filenm = Dir()
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

well, for me your answer did not work and after some looking around i found a little mistake. your code is fine in general, but the "=" sign will not work because

> When no more file names match, Dir returns a zero-length string ("").

at least i think this is the reason it showed nothing for my output. so i would say it works like:

```
Sub LoopThruDirectory2()

Dim strPath As String
Dim strFile As String
Dim x As Integer
strPath = ThisWorkbook.path
strFile = Dir(strPath & "\")
Do While strFile <> ""
    x = x + 1
    Debug.Print strFile
    strFile = Dir    ' Get next entry.
Loop

End Sub
```

feel free to set "thisworkbook.path" as your path and handle strFile as you want. (eg. see above) . for my project the user wanted to pick a chosen folder so i had to use "msoFileDialogFolderPicker". just in case someone has the same problem